# Adding submenus to menu subitems in Joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, submenu, subitem

i want to add a submenu to a menu subitem in Joomla 1.7. Example:

```
[Main menu]
Home
Institutes
  **First Institute**
  Second Intitute
FAQ
Contact

[First Institute submenu]
First link
Second link
Third link
```

On the main menu i've opened Intitutes link and under that i've opened First Institute, which popped another submenu called [First Institute submenu] somewhere else on the page. Now when I navigate on the submenu, the first menu remains the same and link Bold. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a ['Split Menu'](http://www.google.com/search?q=joomla%20split%20menu&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) technique. Here's [one example](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_submenu)